# JDBC RowSets using singleton Connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rowset

I'm using `javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet` and `com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl` to manipulate data. Everything works fine, but I'm getting a warning that I might get a resource leak.

Also, I'm using singleton Connection in JdbcRowSet constructor which is always open, but when I use JdbcRowSet `close()` I can't use it in next method.

Here's the code.

```
public static Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance()
        .getConnection();



(not the exact work, only a sample code)
private static void function1() {

    try {
        JdbcRowSet myrs = new JdbcRowSetImpl(conn);
        myrs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
        myrs.execute();

        //result iteration

        myrs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void function2() {
    same as function1 (for example, not really important here)
}

public static void start(){
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

When it gets to execute `myrs` in `function2()` I get an error:

`at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.execute(Unknown Source)`

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: What happens when you execute function1 twice?

Comment: @FrankOlschewski The same thing as I executed function2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the JdbcRowSetImpl implementation of close

```
public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (rs != null)
        rs.close();
    if (ps != null)
        ps.close();
    if (conn != null)
        conn.close();
}
```

Since the JdbcRowSetImpl.close() will close the connection, the best way to fit with your current architecture might be to create a JdbcRowSet member or instance singleton that is closed when you expect the connection to be classed. Your function1 and function2 would look like this

```
public static Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance()
    .getConnection();
//Implementation of DBRowSet left as an exercise for the ambitious.
public static JdbcRowSet myrs =  DBRowSet.getInstance(); 

private static void function1() {
    try {
        myrs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
        myrs.execute();
        //result iteration
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void function2() {
    try {
        myrs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM `table2`");
        myrs.execute();
        //result iteration
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it? That's great if it is, I don't need to worry about it! Eclipse is getting me that warning when creating an instance of RowSet: `Resource leak: 'myrs' is never closed`. EDIT: If it's atuoclosable, will the Connection remain alive later?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible answer. JdbcRowset being Autocloseble isn't relevant in your case because you aren't using Java 7.

Comment: What if I implement my own JdbcRowSet class and override the `close()` method? Will that help?